# Frobenius inner product proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this mathematical problem?

Let Mat^n×m be the vector space of all n×m-matrices, and let vec: Mat^n×m → R^n·m be the isomorphism that stacks the columns of a given matrix on top of each other, obtaining a long vector.
The Frobenius inner product is the map <−, −>F: Mat^n×m × Mat^n×m → R defined by <A, B>F:= tr(A^T B).
(a) Show that <A, B>F = <vec(A), vec(B)>(where the latter denotes the usual scalar product of R^n·m, i.e. vec(A)^T vec(B)).
(b) Show that the Frobenius inner product is actually an inner product.
(c) Like any inner product, the Frobenius inner product has an associated norm: The Frobenius norm is given by ||A||F:= √ <A, A>F. Show that, if B is an orthogonal matrix, then ||A||F = ||AB||F = ||BA||F

Comment: Here's a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial :)